# Como retornar os registros entre dois valores com o Banco de Dados SQL Server?

Tags: select, sql-server-2012, select-limit

Exemplo da minha tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é a seguinte... Na minha página de notícias destaque tem que aparecer as 2 últimas notícias e na página notícias secundárias tem que a aparecer as 2 outras notícias sequentes.
Exemplo: na destaque a notícias que irão aparecer são as noticias 4 e 3, já na notícia secundaria a 2 e 1.

Eu pensei em usar o LIMIT porém esse comando não existe no SQL Server pelo que me informei ele é apenas do MySQL, também pensei no BETWEEN mas a lógica que use não vingou, ai vi que o Top faz algo parecido com o LIMIT, então no destaque fiz o seguinte comando

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM CADNOTICIAS ORDER BY CODIGO DESC
```

No destaque esta lindo é isso que quero, ta retornando perfeito, a minha dúvida e como fazer no notícias secundarias trazer as notícias 2 e 1. Tudo tem que ser dinâmico no caso de adicionar um notícia 5 na página destaque mostrar noticias 5 e 4 e na noticia secundaria mostra 3 e 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar uma subquery para fazer seu filtro.

A sulução ficar assim;

```
declare @CADNOTICIAS table
(
  CODIGO int,
  THUMB VARCHAR(10),
  TITULO VARCHAR(50),
  TEXTO VARCHAR(100),
  CATEGORIA VARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO @CADNOTICIAS VALUES
(1, 'php.jpg', 'Noticia 1', 'teste', 'Noticia'),
(2, 'php.jpg', 'Noticia 2', 'teste', 'Noticia'),
(3, 'php.jpg', 'Noticia 3', 'teste', 'Noticia'),
(4, 'php.jpg', 'Noticia 4', 'teste', 'Noticia')

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @CADNOTICIAS 
ORDER BY CODIGO DESC

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @CADNOTICIAS 
where CODIGO < (SELECT top 1 CODIGO - 1 FROM @CADNOTICIAS ORDER BY CODIGO DESC)
ORDER BY CODIGO DESC
```

Comment: Perfeito cara, era isso mesmo muito obrigado !